# Can I use an RODC for Active Directory athentication if the writeable DC is not available for several months?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows

We are running an Read-Write DC at our home office which we are using for authentication when were are working there. It works fine as long as we are at the office, but we are going to be on the road for a few months, and and IT infrastructure at our office will have to stay offline during this time.

I read several times that it's not a good idea to expose a DC to the internet, so I was thinking of setting up RODC on a cloud server instead and caching some credentials there.

Would I be able to authenticate against the RODC if the writeable DC was offline for several months? I'm worried that my credentials might be cached at first but expire at a later time.

Comment: Why not just have a VPN between your laptops and the home office DC? Seems like it'd be easier.

Comment: from what i did read about the RODC it can reduce the amount of WAN traffic, which could be nice in off-site locations with bad internet access.

for the question: increase the duration until your credentials expire.

Comment: @Nathan: Unfortunately I cant do that because the home office won't even exist while we are away. All equipment from our office will be in storage during that time.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan is right IMO, but I'll address your actual "questions":

> I read several times that it's not a good idea to expose a DC to the
>   internet, so I was thinking of setting up RODC on a cloud server
>   instead and caching some credentials there.

The RODC still has to replicate with the DC at your HQ.  And the cloud server itself would either have to be exposed to the internet or you'd have to setup a tunnel to that cloud instance (which further upvotes Nathan's comment).

> Would I be able to authenticate against the RODC if the writeable DC
>   was offline for several months? I'm worried that my credentials might
>   be cached at first but expire at a later time.

If the RODC can't get replication from the RWDC then only cached account credentials from users that have authenticated against the RODC while it was able to talk to the RWDC will be allowed to login.

Honestly, Nathan is right...or simply just login to the laptops with cached credentials to begin with...if you aren't connected to the network the laptops will still accept your cached credentials on them.  You might run into issues when you return though with the workstation's account itself having trust relationship issues to the domain if it hasn't contacted the DC in 30 days (by default).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't vpn into the home office's DC because the home office won't even exist while we are away. All equipment from our office will be in storage during that time.

Comment: Then just use cached credentials or create local accounts on your laptops/computers while everything is in storage.

Comment: TheCleaner: I thought of using local accounts as well, but then I'll have to figure out how to offer securely encrypted drive shares between the laptops when using a public WiFi. We'll need that to work on our software while being away. As for cached credentials: Would we be able to share a folder with IPSec encryption when no DC is available?

Comment: Use Dropbox for Business or a similar cloud-hosted environment for file sharing.  Online code repositories as well.  You might even find after relying on such SAAS/IAAS that you like them even better for the mobility they provide.

Comment: I think I found a solution: I'll just stick to local user accounts and buy a cheap travel router like the TP-Link TL-MR3020 or the Asus WL-330N3G for travelling. Thanks for all your help, I'm not sure why you've been downvoted.

Comment: No downvotes that I can see?  Glad you got it worked out.